# Algolia template if no hits are returned

Tags: javascript, algolia

I've implemented my own Algolia PoC based of  https://www.algolia.com/doc/search/auto-complete and I'm now struggling with a specific use case: how can I handle a search which does not return any hits?

Here is my code:

I've been able to identify and detect when/where no hits are returned, but I can't do anything beside just using a console.log(). I tried to get a custom return_msg but I can't call the function. 
I also tried to do some tweak under suggestion: function(suggestion) but this function is never called if no hits are returned.
I also did not found any documentation about this "Templates" section on https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js

```
$('#q').autocomplete({ hint: false }, [
    {
      source: function(q, cb) {
        index.search(q, 
          { hitsPerPage: 10 }, 
          function(error, content) {
                  if (error) {
                    cb([]);
                    return;
                  }

                  if (content.nbHits == 0)
                    { return_msg = '<h5> Sorry, no result </h5>';
                      // DO something here
                      console.log(return_msg);
                     // console.log return "Sorry, no result"
                     }

                  cb(content.hits, content);

                });
          },
      displayKey: 'game',
      templates: {
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return_msg = '<h5> '+ suggestion.MY_ATTRIBUTE + '</h5>'
        return return_msg;
        }
      }
    }
  ]).on('autocomplete:selected', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
     window.location = (suggestion.url);
  });
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `templates` option of your dataset you can specify the template to use when there are no results:

```
source: autocomplete.sources.hits(indexObj, { hitsPerPage: 2 }),
templates: {
  suggestion: // ...
  header:  // ...
  footer:  // ...
  empty: function(options) {
    return '<div>My empty message</div>';
  }
}
```

Full documentation [here](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#datasets).

Comment: Thanks - Works perfectly .. not sure why I missed them on the doc :/